# How can i convert the windows timezone to Java Timezone?

Tags: java, windows

I'm  getting windows time zone as input, which i want to convert it to UTC time in Java. some windows time zone are not same as Java's. 
For example:

Windows time zone = **MPST**(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
equivalent Java time zone = **SGT** (Singapore Standard Time)
My input be like - **13/01/2020 10:46:10 MPST**. so, when i'm trying to convert this date format to UTC, i'm getting **java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "13/01/2020 10:46:10 MPST"**

Please, help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "MPST" isn't a standard time zone identifier known to Java. If it's always "MPST", you can treat that as a literal within the string. (Also: don't use [three-letter time zone identifiers](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ThreeLetterTimeZoneID))

Comment: How have you tried to convert the datetime that lead to the `ParseException`? Please show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid pseudo-codes for time zones

The 2-4 letter pseudo-codes often seen in the media are not actual time zones. Values such as `IST`, `PST`, `CST`, and your `MPST` are not standardized, and are not even unique!

Use only proper time zone names in the format of `Continent/Region`. See this possibly-outdated [list at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

> 020-01-15T08:02:26.612494+08:00[Asia/Kuala_Lumpur]

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/60GFVa).

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class will try to guess the real time zone intended by the use of a 2-4 letter pseudo-zone. For example:

```
String input = "13/01/2020 10:46:10 PST" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss zz") ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
System.out.println( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2020-01-13T10:46:10-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

But guessing `MPST` fails with a runtime error.

## ISO 8601

In any such case as either `PST` or `MPST`, you really should go back to the source of the data. **Educate those people about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard** designed for the purpose of exchanging date-time values as text.

By the way, the `toString` method of the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class seen above extends the ISO 8601 standard format by wisely appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.